# Prove that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\sin^2{x}}}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(2n)!(\sqrt{\sin{x}})^{4n}}{4^n (n!)^2}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Prove that
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\sin^2{x}}}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(2n)!(\sqrt{\sin{x}})^{4n}}{4^n (n!)^2}$$

Comment: Do you mean:
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\sin^2{x}}}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(2n)!(\sqrt{\sin{x}})^{4n}}{4^n (n!)^2}$$

Comment: Yes☝☝☝☝☝☝☝☝☝☝☝☝☝☝☝☝

Comment: Ok, the ambiguity of the problem is now settled. What are your thoughts and what have you tried to solve the problem? That way, we don't repeat information you already know.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**. One may use the [generalized binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Generalizations) (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/124293/generalized-binomial-theorem)) to get,
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-u}}=(1-u)^{-1/2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{{2n\choose n}}{2^{2n}}u^{n}
&, \qquad |u|<1,
\end{eqnarray*}$$ then one may put $u:=\sin^2 x$.