# Binomial expansions of index

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

Why the binomial expansion of $(1+x)^n$, $n$ belongs to negative integer or fraction, is 
$$
1+nx+n(n-1)x^2/2........
$$
I admit the expansion when $n$ is positive integer, is because of Pascal triangle.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. Note [Newton's generalized binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton's_generalized_binomial_theorem) gives a basic explanation of this.

Comment: But Pascal triangle is for +ve integers only.

Comment: The generalised binomial sum is $(1+x)^r = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\begin{bmatrix}
           r \\
           k
         \end{bmatrix} x^k$ for $r$ a fraction or negative power. You can prove it by finding the Taylor series of $(1+x)^r$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generalized binomial theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/124293/generalized-binomial-theorem)

Answer (score 0):

Well, for a negative integers $n$ you just need a simple substitution , for example assume we want to expand $1+x$ for $n=-3$, based on the formula we have:

setting $-3=n$ follows:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{∞}{{n}\choose{k}}x^{k}$$$$={{n}\choose{0}}x^{0}+{{n}\choose{1}}x^{1}+{{n}\choose{2}}x^{2}+...$$$$=\frac{n!}{0!n!}x^{0}+\frac{n!}{1!\left(n-1\right)!}x^{1}+\frac{n!}{2!\left(n-2\right)!}x^{2}$$$$=1+nx+\frac{n\left(n-1\right)}{2}x^{2}$$

Wow substitute back:

$$=1-3x+6x^{2}-...$$

Also duo to the convergence we need the upper limit of the sum to be $∞$

Comment: But this is for +ve integers because of Pascal triangle.